# Add Tooltip using Aspose API for a PDF

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells, aspose.pdf

I am trying add a tooltip text in a FTL template file to generate a PDF. Can anyone please help me how we can add it? 
Here is a sample:

```
<Table ColumnWidth="100%">
   <row>
       <cell>
           <segment> Hi How are you..!  </segment>
       </cell>
   </row>
</Table>
```

When i hover over the Text "Hi How are you..!" i want add a description. Can someone please help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can add Annotations inside PDF after generating it and control their visibility by adding JavaScript Actions for mouse in/out. This way, it would look/act like a tooltip. Please check following code snippet, in order to achieve your requirement.

```
Document doc = new Document(dataDir + "Tooltip.pdf");

// search target text
TextFragmentAbsorber tfa = new TextFragmentAbsorber("Hello World!");
doc.getPages().get_Item(1).accept(tfa);
Page page = doc.getPages().get_Item(1);
String name = "TXTANNOT";
String title = "Tooltip";
String comment = "Hi How Are You?";

// add a text annotation
TextAnnotation text = new TextAnnotation(page, tfa.getTextFragments().get_Item(1).getRectangle());
text.setName(name);
text.setTitle(title);
text.setContents(comment);

// These flags must be raised to suppress showing of annotation icon
text.setFlags(AnnotationFlags.NoView | AnnotationFlags.ReadOnly);
page.getAnnotations().add(text);
com.aspose.pdf.Rectangle popupRect = new com.aspose.pdf.Rectangle(90, 610, 235, 710);

// Add popup annotation
PopupAnnotation popup = new PopupAnnotation(page, popupRect);
page.getAnnotations().add(popup);
text.setPopup(popup);
popup.setParent(text);

Field field = new ButtonField(page, tfa.getTextFragments().get_Item(1).getRectangle());
doc.getForm().add(field);

String fieldName = field.getPartialName();
String openScript = "var t = this.getAnnot(this.pageNum, '" + name + "'); t.popupOpen = true; var w = this.getField('" + fieldName + "'); w.setFocus();";
String closeScript = "var t = this.getAnnot(this.pageNum, '" + name + "'); t.popupOpen = false;";

PdfAction openaction = new JavascriptAction(openScript);
PdfAction closeaction = new JavascriptAction(closeScript);

// set button actions
field.getActions().setOnEnter(openaction);
field.getActions().setOnExit(closeaction);
doc.save(dataDir + "ToolTip_out.pdf");
```

Please check generated [output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2pmcdyr182b2ri/ToolTip_out.pdf?dl=0) by above code, for your reference.

*PS: I work at Aspose as Support Developer.*